# Installing Symfony 2 on Mac

Tags: macos, symfony, installation

I am new with Symfony and I cannot manage to install it on my MAC book pro (version 10.9.5).
I go the the Terminal and execute this code (as explained but in a folder "symphony" I created in MyDocuments):

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Sophie:~ sophiejarlier$ cd Documents
MacBook-Pro-de-Sophie:Documents sophiejarlier$ sudo curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /symfony
MacBook-Pro-de-Sophie:Documents sophiejarlier$
```

But nothing has been installed, the folder symphony is empty... Should I install something else before? I am lost...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are new in terminal also. What you done is just you downloaded symfony installer in your main root directory `/` where is main stuff like /var, /usr etc.

Answer (score 0):

You forgotten the installation part.

Move your symfony installer (just downloaded) using :

```
$ sudo mv /symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

Give execution permissions :

```
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

Then, go (open a terminal) in your webserver directory (default `/Library/WebServer/Documents`).
And do your install by executing the following command :

```
$ symfony new name_of_your_project
```

Your project is created in the folder `name_of_your_project` of your current directory.

All the instructions are coming from the [documentation](http://symfony.com/download)